# How do you bind SQL Data to a .NET DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, data-binding

I am trying to bind a table in an SQL database to a DataGridView Control. I would like to make it so that when the user enters a new line of data in the DataGridView that a record is automatically added to the database. Here is my current attempt...

```
    BOMClassesDataContext DB = new BOMClassesDataContext();

    Form_Load()
    {
        var mfrs = from m in DB.Manufacturers
                   select m;

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = mfrs;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }

    dataGridView_CellValueChanged()
    {
        try
        {
            DB.SubmitChanges()
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

If I click the bottom empty row it automatically fills in the ID (identity) column of the table with a "0" instead of the next unused value. If I change that value manually to the next available then it adds the new record fine but if I leave it at 0 it does nothing. How can i fix this? In my LINQ to SQL classes the ID column of the table has the AutoGenerate property set to true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute `DB.SubmitChanges()` when the user has finished.

With Linq To SQL, no changes are made to the underlying database until you do that.

Comment: Ok, that works as long as I enter the ID (identity column) in manually. Is there a way to get it to automatically increment the ID column? The ID column is setup as an Identity.

Comment: Also on what event is it best to use to fire the SubmitChanges method? CellValueChanged?

Comment: @Jordan: In your Linq-To-Sql designer, change the ID column's "Auto Generated Property" value to True.  Hide it from the data grid unless there is a reason for the users to see it.

Comment: @Jordan:  You should update your question to include your follow up questions, or you should ask new questions to address the follow up questions.

Comment: @magnifico, can you give me a little more info how to do that??